# Jekyll and Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm working on a project of mine with jekyll and github pages. I created a repo on Github  (https://github.com/liftedteam/liftedteam.github.io), and then I created a local jekyll site and linked it with the repo.  At the beginning everything was ok, when I applied a theme today, on localhost (jekyll serve) it displayed fantastic, but when i pushed to the host through my terminal, on the website it displays in the way you can see at https://liftedteam.github.io/lifted it gives me that error.. But on the repo I can see all the files that I have locally. Furthermore, if I only type the website url without the /lifted subroot,it only shows the html, even if it should show an error instead. Can you please help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_config.yml` file, you have `baseurl: "/lifted"`. In the README of the template you're using, it says the baseurl should be `""`.

I cloned your repo and changed `"/lifted"` to `""` and ran `bundle install`, `jekyll build`, and `jekyll serve` and the site displayed properly.

The reason for this is that the site uses the baseurl to reference assets. So, instead of root/js, it's trying to reach javascript files at root/lifted/js, which doesn't exist.

GitHub Pages work in that if your repository is named username.github.io, the site will be at that address. If you want the home page of your site to be username.github.io/lifted, you'll have to create a repository named Lifted instead of username.github.io

The reason for this is that username.github.io should typically be the "Home Page" of your GitHub account, while other repositories can be accessed from your home page (this is one way to take advantage of the way it's set up).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try this afternoon. So if I put base url to "" the website homeoage won't be liftedteam.github.io/lifted but only  liftedteam.github.io right?

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm new here as well. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.